# Version control (`git`) for a file outside of the controlled directory - linking won't do

Tags: git, filesystems, ln

I have a git repository that depends on an external (to the repo) file which is frequently and irregularly regenerated. It will always have the same name, but not always the same inode. I can't use a symlink since `git` won't follow it and I won't get the necessary file if I clone the repo elsewhere. I can't use a hard link, since the closed-source program that generates the file doesn't edit in-place but deletes and remakes it breaking the hard link.

Short of going down the route of `inotify` scripting is there any simple solution to this?